# C# how to check if var contains constructor Params

Tags: c#

using System;

```
namespace Exercise_7
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Sex;
        public string Father;
        public string Mother;

        public Dog(string name, string sex)
        {
            Name = name;
            Sex = sex;
        }

        public Dog(string name, string sex, string father, string mother)
        {
            Father = father;
            Mother = mother;
            Name = name;
            Sex = sex;
        }

       public string DogsOverall()
        {
            return $"Name {Name}, sex{Sex}, fathers name is {Father}, mothers name is {Mother}";
        }
```

Basically, there is some vars that does not contain Father or Mother, so how can i check that? or like how to i print instead of nothing - "unknown"?

Comment: Please look at the if then else statement, its one of the primary tenants of most programming languages, and if you don't know how to use it you will never be able to write a program https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i print instead of nothing - "unknown"?

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
public string DogsOverall()
{
    return $"Name {Name ??  "unknown"}, sex{Sex ??  "unknown"}, fathers name is {Father ??  "unknown"}, mothers name is {Mother ??  "unknown"}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for better constructors you can edit to this

```
public Dog(string name, string sex)
        {
            Name = name;
            Sex = sex;
        }

        public Dog(string name, string sex, string father, string mother):this(name,sex)
        {
            Father = father;
            Mother = mother;
        }
```

and in DogOverall you can check any prop beafor print

Answer (score 0):

You can call the second constructor from your first one and pass in "unknown" for example.

You can also use the ?? operator to use a fallback value when/if father/mother is null.

```
namespace Exercise_7
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Sex;
        public string Father;
        public string Mother;

        public Dog(string name, string sex) : this(name, sex, "unknown", "unknown")
        {
        }

        public Dog(string name, string sex, string father, string mother)
        {
            Father = father ?? "unknown";
            Mother = mother ?? "unknown";
            Name = name;
            Sex = sex;
        }

   public string DogsOverall()
    {
        return $"Name {Name}, sex{Sex}, fathers name is {Father}, mothers name is {Mother}";
    }
```